# Use abstract class with x-www-form-urlencoded content-type

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I have an abstract class

```java
public abstract class AbstractClazz {

    private String discriminator;

    // getter, setter
}
```

and I have multiple implementations of this class, one of them could look like this

```java
public class ConcreteClazz {

    private String value;

    // getter, setter
}
```

also I have an endpoint that consumes x-www-form-urlencoded content type only.

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(AbstractClazz abstractClazz) {
    System.out.println(abstractClazz);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

What I want to achieve is to deserialize to a concrete class based on the discriminator parameter in AbstractClazz. I've tried using jackson @JsonSybTypes and @JsonTypeInfo annotations on the abstract class but it only works if the payload comes as json in request body and not as x-www-form-urlencoded content.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "discriminator")
@JsonSubTypes(@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteClazz.class, name = "concrete"))
public abstract class AbstractClazz {

    private String discriminator;

    // getter, setter
}
```

Is there a way how to achieve the same behavior with x-www-form-urlencoded content type?
The error I get is

```
Request processing failed: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.AbstractClazz]: Is it an abstract class?] with root cause

java.lang.InstantiationException: null
```

Comment: As you noticed jackson deals with json payloads. [FormHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html) handles `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I'm not sure if this will work, but you can try extending it to create a class to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation that combines query parameters and form data into a single map called "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body like below:

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {}
```

Then you can use an [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance to convert your `Map<String, String>` parameters to a subclass of your `AbstractClazz` depending from the value of the *discriminator* key obtaining the expected result:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AbstractClazz clazz = mapper.convertValue(parameters, AbstractClazz.class); 
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```